# boolean equation

Tags: computer-science, boolean-logic

Can someone check if this is the right equation for the diagram:

C = (Not A) AND B

[alt text http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/3572/111dfh.jpg](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/3572/111dfh.jpg)

Comment: Now seriously, I'm beginning to think somebody's having a laugh here, and it ain't me.

Comment: Diagram of what? Of a logical circuit?

Comment: Yes it matches the diagram perfectly.

Comment: To upload an image : http://imageshack.us/ (for instance ; first result in google for "how to upload an image", for me)

Comment: NO ive got the diagram but cant seem to copy it to show you so can someone tell how can i do that then you guys can check if its right im not having a laugh

Comment: Dave, looking at your posting history, it seems like you're just bombarding the site with really terrible, non-sensical, bad questions. You're not going to go very far here with that kind of attitude. Put at least some minimal effort and thought in to your questions, and realise that we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: IRBMe ive done my homework just wanted to see if it right whats wrong in that and what attitude am i showing

Comment: Neil Butterworth, Dreas Grech, Greg Beech, Michael Borgwardt, Pascal MARTIN why in the hell have you closed the question just wanted to check my work

Comment: First of all, tag it with "homework", second, format your sentences in a civilised, literate manner. We are some kind of scientists here after all.

Comment: kek444 wat you want me to do call you queen

Comment: Well now you did make me laugh :) No, simply use capital letters and interpunction properly. A question mark at the end of the sentence would do wonders.

Comment: @dave s - Because (a) It's nothing to do with computer programming, and (b) you couldn't be bothered to make the effort to work out how to upload an image before posting so the question made no sense. The only difficult decision was whether to close it as "not programming related" or "not a real question".

Comment: Oh yeah, and given that in the diagram there are two NOT gates and one AND gate, and your answer involves only one NOT and one AND, it's so obviously wrong that it means you haven't made any effort whatsoever to get it right.

Comment: @dave : Because you did apparently no effort when asking your question : you did not even bother searching how to upload the image... Looking at your profile and the previous questions you asked, this kind of question is not the first one (each one of your questions on stackoverflow has been downvoted between 2 and 7 times...) ; still, I indicated you imageshack, as a sign that people here still hope you can do better for your next questions)

Comment: This is definitely **programming related**.  If you didn't learn the fundamental logic gates as a part of your programming education, that's no reason to penalize those who are trying to learn them.

Comment: OK for the re-opening, I understand the reasons (maybe I was too quick on the trigger) ; but why has the picture been removed ?

Comment: @Pascal: I think the OP and I were editing at the same time.  I rolled back to a revision where the diagram is visible.

Comment: As it happens, I did learn about them. However, they are no more programming related than is theory of magnetism (necessary to know how hard disks work).

Comment: @Neil: I would disagree, it may not be programming, but it definetly is programming-related. Logical gates are simply logical conditions in a different form, and DeMorgan's laws get applied often in both programming and logical circuits.

Comment: @Neil: If you can't see how basic logic is far more programming related than the theory of magnetism then there's no help for you.  I won't waste my time arguing.

Comment: @Bill a masterful rejoinder, and about what I've come to expect.

Comment: @Bill - The question isn't about the implementation of logic gates in programming, or the applicability of De Morgan's laws to programming. It's essentially a "please do my physics homework" question. While I concur the programming would be impossible without physics, and this skirts somewhere near the boundaries of computer programming related, it isn't quite there.

Comment: @Greg: Sorry, but this is digital logic, has *nothing* to do with physics. Electronics has to do with physics, but this is really Boolean algebra, even if it is homework in a cheeky wrapper.

Comment: @Greg Beech: It doesn't have to be in implementation of logic gates in a programming language to be programming related.  The OP didn't just ask for the answer, he gave his answer and asked for input.  In my mind that's not asking "please do my homework" since he did make an effort at an answer.  To me, that's what puts this question just on the acceptable side of the boundary.

Comment: Suppose we could get into the meet of the matter and design a fully functional, Microprocessor in Logic symbols?? including flip flops memory registers.  BTW. it is what the upper levels of programs are eventually turned into.  :)  And btw how does Physics remotely play into programming??.  Computing Science is purely mathmatical, With Material science.  I can see the physics of an electron as it travels at near the speed of light and distance between transistors. Capacitance. The physical char of the transistor itself? latching voltage??  just wondering?? I work on the equipment that makes em

Comment: @ mods - the reasons the mods cite for why questions should be closed are almost always wrong.  This is totally programming related, but it's homework! c'mon guys!

Answer (score 13):

Now that you've actually posted the diagram, no, that is not the correct equation. You've missed the second inverter which negates the final result. So it should be `C = NOT ((NOT A) AND B)` which is equivelant to `C = A OR (NOT B)` by [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: Those reading the above comment. Ignore it, I edited the answer.